# Can I Get/Upload the files from local with the file path stored in a varibale in angular/typescript/javaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, file, file-upload

**Is it possible from the UI perspective to automatically upload the files using input type=file from user's local machine , where the path of the file is stored in a variable(vraible get the path from API call)**

Comment: No. The browser has no access to the file system without user action. [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications)

Comment: @Randy Casburn..thanks.Any alternative?can I store the path in a variable from input type file..full absolute path..is that possible?

Comment: You can store anything you want in a variable, but you cannot use even a full absolute path to access the file system. Modern browsers substitute something along the lines of `C:\fakepath` for the fullpath during file operations. This is done specifically so we devs cannot discover the file structure. If you attempt to set the value of the file input, you will either get a `typeError` thrown or will be presented a `Security Error`; both will prevent your operation. In terms of **alternatives**, if this is a hard and fast requirement, consider using something like Electron.

Comment: @Randy Casburn ..thanks a lot for the explanation